# React doesnt return img in document from list-src

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

React doesnt return img in document from list-src

import React from 'react'

export default function dio() {

```
var storys = [
    {
        src: './images/profilna.jpg'
    },
    {
        src: './images/profilna.jpg'
    },
]

return (<div>
    <div >
        <img src="./images/profilna.jpg" alt=""/>
        {
            storys.forEach(story => {
            //this dont return img in document
           return( <img src={story.src} />
  )
            })

        }
    </div>
</div>
)
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using .map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `.forEach()` has no return, try with `.map()`

```
export default function dio() {

var storys = [
    {
        src: './images/profilna.jpg'
    },
    {
        src: './images/profilna.jpg'
    },
]

return (<div>
    <div >
        <img src="./images/profilna.jpg" alt=""/>
        {
            storys.map(story => {
              return( <img src={story.src} />
                )
            })

        }
    </div>
</div>
)
}
```